# How to use subqueries in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Hello I'm trying to solve this question with a subquery:

Select names, service number, jobs and salaries of
people working in the same city as HAVET. (havet is a name)

And I have only two table the first one is the emp table with the column (noserv, name, job, salaries) and the second one is the SERV table with the column (noserv, nameserv, city)

I know that I have to use a subquery but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You should not need a subquery, just a join.

Comment: read this =>  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/joins.php

Answer (score 1):

Semi-pseudocode (CTE won't work, obviously).

```
with emp (noserv, name, job, salaries),
     serv (noserv, nameserv, city)
-- This is what you're looking for, I presume
select e.*
from emp e join serv s on e.noserv = s.noserv
where s.city = -- subquery returns city where HAVET lives
               (select s1.city 
                from serv s1 join emp e1 on e1.noserv = s1.noserv
                where e1.name = 'HAVET'
               );
```

Comment: Not really, but I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-- This is a normal query with a left join
select *
from emp e
left join s on e.noserv = s.noserv
where s.city = 

-- get Havet's city from the subquery.
(select s.city
from emp e
left join s on e.noserv = s.noserv
where e.name = 'HAVET')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, change the column name according to your table and column names.

```
Select e.name,e.serviceNubmer,e.Job,e.salaries 
from emp e,serv s 
where 
e.noserv = s.noserv 
and s.city ='HAVET';
```

Comment: what is the error? or result? please provide expected output and query you have tried to get the same.

Comment: `code` Select e.nom, e.noserv, e.emploi,e.sal 
from emp e,serv s 
where 
e.noserv = s.noserv 
and s.ville = 'HAVET'; `code` I have a blank output and I need all the employee that are working in the same city of Mister 'havet'